# How to draw a function curve in android?

Tags: android

I have a function, y = 50sin(x/50) + 100.
Now what i want to do is to draw a curve for this function, but without any additional info from the graph plotters, I just need a wave on the screen. The X should correspond to my X parameter of the screen and Y to the Y parameter of the screen.
Here is the code of my current view.

```
public class Sinusoid extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Sinusoid(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //todo draw the line using myFunction
    }

    private double myFunction(double x){
        return 50 * Math.sin(x / 50) + 100;
    }

}
```

Now the question is, what should i fill in my TODO?

Please help, any documentation or example will be very useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to have something like this:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int x=0; x<canvas.getWidth();x++) {

        canvas.drawPoint(x,(float) myFunction(x),mPaint);
    }
}
```

But you'll eventually need to adjust the value of your function given the canvas height.

Comment: but will this be a continuous line?

Comment: Yes, if you set the paint stroke width large enough (for example `mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f)` )

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    float xv=x0,yv= yo,x,y;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxPoints; i++) {
        x=i * scalex;
        y=function(i)*scaley;
        canvas.drawLine(xv, yv, x, y, paint);
        xv=x;
        yv=y;
    }
```

The graphic will appears continuous.